# Central Authentication Service (CAS) and HttpWebRequest - Authentication

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, cas

I'm using HttpWebRequest to get data from websites. Currently I want to get data from website, which is secured by CAS system. I'm sending and receving headers via HttpWebRequest (C#) and all is ok. Unfortunately when I want to get certain pages, then I got message "Automatically logged out.". I checked headers in LiveHttpHeaders (Firefox Add-On), and all my headers in my C# app and in Firefox are the same.

Example (headers from Firefox):

https://www.example.com/balance/ > Moved temporarily to:
https://www.example.com/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%3A443%2Fbalance%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check

In web browser all is working. In C# app nope.

Comment: Is your HttpWebRequest session authenticating to CAS before you hit the resource that is redirecting you? Are you also passing cookies along between request?

Comment: Cookies are shared between requests. When I want get secured page in FF, then browser automatically moved me to CAS service. In C# app I want get secured page as well, and I'm redirecting to CAS service also, but in C# app I got message that I'm logged out. I tried reverse headers (firstly to CAS page, and then to right page, but this way doesn't work too).

Comment: What's the URL of the page that is telling you that you are logged out? is it cas's?

Comment: Yes, it's CAS, this one (I removed real domain): https://www.example.com/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%3A443%2Fbalance%2Fj_spring_cas_security_check

Comment: That's interesting. I can't think of an instance when /cas/login would tell you that you are logged out. Usually it will tell you that you are logged in, if no service parameter is passed. The logout message is usually shown in /cas/logout.

Comment: Exactly, in webbrowser I've got message that I'm logged in, in C# app that I'm automatically logged out. I will check my C# app again, maybe I forget some paramaters or sth.